# How to add new repository in CentOs

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, centos, sudo, mkdir

I am trying to install readR package from R on EC2 instance.

I found a solution on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945512/r-ubuntu-cant-install-packages-readr-and-eurostat):

I would like the script for CentOS but the answer is for Ubuntu:

```
[1] apt-get update     # refresh
[2] apt-get install software-properties-common
[3] add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/rrutter"
[4] add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/c2d4u"
[5] apt-get update     # now with new repos
[6] apt-get install r-cran-readr
```

Below is my attempt to translate, I understood line 2 is not necesary in my case, and what I am missing are the two lines allowing to add repositories in CentOs:

```
sudo yum update
sudo mkdir ppa:marutter/rrutter
sudo mkdir ppa:marutter/c2d4u
sudo yum update
sudo yum install r-cran-readr
```

Help much appreciated !

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: https://www.devopsroles.com/add-repositories-on-linux/

Answer (score -1):

Try using config-manager it works for me

yum-config-manager --add-repo=ppa:marutter/rrutter

Comment: Says Cannot add repo from ppa:----/-----: URL must be http, ftp, file or https not "ppa"