# Installation of package. "had non-zero exit status" error. "S3 methods" error

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I need the `MVN` package for multivariate normality test.
During it's installation, my laptop turned off.

After it restarted when I wanted to install `MVN` again, I got various "had non-zero exit status" that were gone after installing `libcurl` etc.
But now, I have other errors.

```
> install.packages("MVN")
Installing package into ‘/home/mslaav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘kableExtra’

próbowanie adresu URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/kableExtra_0.9.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1638582 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

próbowanie adresu URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/MVN_5.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 342047 bytes (334 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 334 KB

* installing *source* package ‘kableExtra’ ...
** pakiet ‘kableExtra’ został pomyślnie rozpakowany oraz sumy MD5 zostały sprawdzone
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Ostrzeżenie: S3 methods ‘[.spec_tbl_df’, ‘as.col_spec.NULL’, ‘as.col_spec.character’, ‘as.col_spec.col_spec’, ‘as.col_spec.default’, ‘as.col_spec.list’, ‘format.col_spec’, ‘output_column.POSIXt’, ‘output_column.default’, ‘output_column.double’, ‘print.col_spec’, ‘print.collector’, ‘print.date_names’, ‘print.locale’, ‘str.col_spec’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘readr.so’ not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘kableExtra’
* removing ‘/home/mslaav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/kableExtra’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘kableExtra’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘kableExtra’ is not available for package ‘MVN’
* removing ‘/home/mslaav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/MVN’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘MVN’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpF6Tden/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried reinstalling R and Rstudio, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please check this answer it might be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543983/non-zero-exit-when-installing-package-only-tidyverse

Comment: Did you try installing kableExtra directly?

Comment: Can't install kableExtra becouse "package ‘kavleExtra’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)".
Can't install readr, "package or namespace load failed for ‘readr’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)", plus "S3 methods ‘[.spec_tbl_df’, ‘as.col_spec.NULL’, ‘as.col_spec.character’, ‘as.col_spec.col_spec’, ‘as.col_spec.default’, ‘as.col_spec.list’, ‘format.col_spec’, ‘output_column.POSIXt’, ‘output_column.default’, ‘output_column.double’, ‘print.col_spec’, ‘print.collector’, ‘print.date_names’, ‘print.locale’, ‘str.col_spec’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found" as with other packages

Comment: Try `install.packages("readr", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))`

Comment: Okay, I missed this part, thanks for pointing it. It fixed problems and MVN installed and works perfectly, although the S3 Warning is still there. 
Let's hope it won't interfere for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [non zero exit when installing package, only tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543983/non-zero-exit-when-installing-package-only-tidyverse)