# Got stuck while installing pool package in in aws ubuntu server

Tags: amazon-web-services, shiny, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install pool package for my shiny app in ubuntu AMI in aws.
I used command 
** R -e "install.packages('pool', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')“**
but it got stuck.
Is there any solution apart from upgrading the instance t2.micro(which is under free tier) to some high level as i don't want to get bill from aws

Comment: Consider using http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/.

Comment: Are the groups set up properly? Do you have access to the Internet from the instance?

Comment: @Passatizhi i am installing all packages from putty and default page of shiny is also visible when i browse ip_address:3838.I am not getting what you are saying but hope it answered your question.

Comment: I think problem is with dplyr package when it try to install as dependency it is throwing error ** ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-dplyr’ **

Comment: If its compiling something, then you might not have enough of RAM to install it. I had a similar issue before on my micro instance also, have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945512/r-ubuntu-cant-install-packages-readr-and-eurostat