# readr package not installing on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, cran, readr

Hello I am trying to install reader onto my Ubuntu VPS. I only have 1 GB of RAM which is why I can not install it. I came across Dirk's post [R (Ubuntu) - Can't install packages "readr" and "eurostat"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945512/r-ubuntu-cant-install-packages-readr-and-eurostat) where he explained the work around.

```
apt-get update     # refresh
apt-get install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/rrutter"
add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/c2d4u"
apt-get update     # now with new repos
apt-get install r-cran-readr
```

However, when I run the code. The final line gives me this error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-readr : Depends: r-api-3.4
                Depends: r-cran-rcpp but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: r-cran-tibble but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: r-cran-hms but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: r-cran-r6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I was able to install all the packages separately and tried running the code again. I got the same error. I am not to sure what my next steps should be.

Edit**

I am trying to follow Dirk's advice in the comment section. I am having a difficult time understanding what to do with the "deb" file. Once I have the deb link

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
```

Some sources to me to run the command

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

However, I recieve this error.

```
keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

It seems like I have to add the deb link to a directory. I am brand new to Ubuntu and the shell. If someone could explain this to me in simple terms that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you haven't upgraded R yet.  Starting from your distro version (18.04? You didn't say!) get the PPA at CRAN for R (and a few packages) first.  Get R current.  _Then_ add the Rutter PPAs which build on the current R.  You may be able to force R in as well.  Good luck.

Comment: Hey @DirkEddelbuettel ! Thanks for your reply. I edited my post to include my next steps. I am still having a bit of trouble. Thanks for your time to help me out.